# How to resize a range of cells pasted as a picture on email body using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a code that copies a range of cells and paste it as a picure on the body of an e-mail. The problem is that when the picture is pasted, it´s really small and hard to read it. How can I resize the picture?
Because when I paste the same range of cells manually, it´s in the perfect size, but when using the code, it´s really small

[image: The e-mail looks like this:]

The code I have:

```
Sub mandar_email_cotacao()


Dim ol As Object 'Outlook.Application
Dim olEmail As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
Dim olInsp As Object 'Outlook.Inspector
Dim wd As Object 'Word.Document

Sheets("Polishop2").Range("ab64:ak121").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Set ol = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") '/* if outlook is running, create otherwise */
Set olEmail = ol.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

With olEmail
    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    If olInsp.EditorType = 4 Then 'olEditorWord
        Set wd = olInsp.WordEditor
        wd.Range.PasteAndFormat 13 'wdChartPicture
    End If
    .Display
    .To = Range("F2")
End With

    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, before copying the range in Excel you can change the size by using the following code:

```
Range("ab64:ak121").Font.Size = 12
```

Also you can try using the `xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme` value from the [XlPasteType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype) which specifies the formatting to use when pasting the selected table cells.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Set wordDoc = Mail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        With wordDoc.Range
        .pasteandformat wdchartpicture
        With wordDoc.InlineShapes(1)
        .ScaleHeight = 100
        End With
        End With
```